# In Keynote is there a way to lock a presentation in slideshow mode?

Tags: ipad, keynote, multi-touch

In Keynote is there a way to lock a presentation in slideshow mode?  I work at a children's museum and want the kids to interact with the iPad and be able to switch between slides, but not be able to exit into editing mode or do anything else to the slideshow. I have tried Guided Access and limiting certain areas they can touch, but there are still certain finger gestures, swiping down with two fingers and holding down one finger, that will allow kids to exit into editing mode or go into "drawing mode" on the iPad.  If Keynote doesn't allow you to do this, is there another slideshow app that can?  Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful to add the version of iPadOS that is running on this iPad to your original question. Without that info we will likely not be able to help...

Comment: It is an iPad Mini 2 and is currently running iOS 12.4.5